# Make XHR from Dart Server

Tags: dart

I'm trying to figure out how to create an XHR from inside a Dart running on the server. All the examples, tutorials, and docs that I have been able to find (such as https://www.dartlang.org/articles/json-web-service/) recommend using the `HttpRequest` class in the `dart:html` library. Unfortunately, that library is not available on the stand-alone VM, which means I can't use it from a server-side context.  The `HttpRequest` class in the `dart:io` library is abstract, and further more doesn't seem to have any methods outside of ones meant for handling incoming requests, rather than creating new ones. Having a server-side application make requests to outside APIs seems a common enough thing, but I find anything explaining how to do it. So, how do you create an outgoing request from a server-side Dart application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either use the [`HttpClient`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.HttpClient) class from `dart:io` - there is a very basic example in that link.

OR you could use the [`http` pub package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http) which might be a little bit easier to use. Example from their pub page:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = "http://example.com/whatsit/create";
http.post(url, body: {"name": "doodle", "color": "blue"})
    .then((response) {
  print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
  print("Response body: ${response.body}");
});
```

Comment: The HttpClient class was exactly what I needed. Thanks for pointing me to it - it was impossible to find through Googling (but hopefully this SO question will help that in the future).